# Should spam questions and inappropriate humiliating questions get deleted?

Tags: discussion

I noticed in this site and in other stackoverover sites, some people posts inappropriate questions.
In one of those sites, a user posted a humiliating sexual question, or here a user posted spam question that is similar to an advertizing.
Shouldn’t a moderator to delete this answer quickly? Better then for a such negative question to exists and being shown to teh new arrival?

I though voting before deleting a post is for those question that may have points a view, but a qestion not even close to the subject shouldn't be wait to delete

Answer (score 8):

**Use your spam and offensive flags.**

It only takes 6 of them for the post to be deleted automatically. Of course, a moderator can instantly delete the post, if they happen to see it before the 6 flags accumulate (assuming of course they agree with you that the post is spam or offensive).